# Angular filter html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Tenho um ng-repeat que me retorna uma lista.

Toda linha, tenho um texto padrão que surge se uma variável for > 0

Até aí tudo funcionando.

Como faço para adicionar no filter somente mostrar o registro quando o texto padrão estiver preenchido?

O conteúdo está numa div:

```
<div name="pesq" id "pesq" style="padding-left: 5px;color:red"> =texto padrão= </div>


<tr ng-repeat="nome in nomes | filter: 'pesq'">
```

Comment: Lucas, seria basicamente mostrar na lista somente os registros que tiverem o texto da div preenchido

Answer (score 3):

Pode fazer:

```
<tr ng-repeat="[objecto] in [colecção] | filter: {[propriedade]: '[texto]'}">
```

Onde `propriedade` é o nome da propriedade do objecto que pretende usar para filtar, e `texto` é o texto que pretende encontrar na propriedade.

Ou seja, (assumindo que o nome da propriedade é `pesq` e o texto é `padrao`):

```
<tr ng-repeat="nome in nomes | filter: {pesq: 'padrao'}">
```

Todos os objectos `nome` que contenham a propriedade `pesq` com o texto `padrao` serão escritos no DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, uma opção seria fazer isso apenas com css e jquery. Você pode deixar por padrão o texto escondido com `display:none` ou deixando-o invisível com `visibility:hidden`,  ai na sua condição, você apenas capturaria o elemento com jquery e adicionaria o css. Exemplo `$('#elemento').css("display","block");` ou `$('#elemento').css("visibility",visible");`
Se tiver alguma dúvida comenta ai :D

```js
$('#inp').focusout(function(){
   if($(this).val().length >0)
   {
     $('#texto').css('display','block')
   }
   else{
     alert('tamanho menor que 0')
     $('#texto').css('display','none')
   }

})
```

```css
#texto{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p id='texto' > texto exibido </p>

<input type="text" id="inp"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"> </script>
```

Comment: obrigado pela dica, talvez seja um caminho... tem algum exemplo?

Comment: @user103907 editei a resposta, testa ai! Digite um texto e clique fora do input, depois clique no input e clique fora dele sem digitar nada.